# Points within a circle

Tags: numpy, geometry

I am trying to find the points within a circle by using numpy.where():

```
coord=[]
    
    
x=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
y=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
    
coord.append(x)     
coord.append(y)

neighbouring_points= np.where(np.roots((coord[0]-coord[0][10])**2 + (coord[1]-coord[1][10])**2)<=0.01,) 
                              #protein_coordinates[0],
                              #protein_coordinates[1],)
                              
                              
                              #np.delete(protein_coordinates[0],protein_coordinates[0][10]),
                              #np.delete(protein_coordinates[1],protein_coordinates[1][10]))

plt.scatter(coord[0],coord[1], color='blue')
```

The result is that all points are selected and not only those satisfying the condition, I have also tried to add x,y alongside the condition to satisfy:

```
coord=[]
    
    
x=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
y=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
    
coord.append(x)     #easier to plot than "protein_coordinates.append([x,y])"
coord.append(y)

neighbouring_points= np.where(np.roots((coord[0]-coord[0][10])**2 + (coord[1]-coord[1][10])**2)<=0.01, 
                              coord[0],
                              coord[1],)
```

In this last case I get the error:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (999,) (1000,) (1000,)

I have fixed the error by removing the centre of the circle, but the code still does not work.

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: I think you're looking for `np.sqrt`, not `np.roots`...

Answer (score 0):

1. you are not using the correct formula for the circle. Use `np.sqrt()` instead of `np.roots`
2. you are not correctly plotting your points. Use

```
idx = neighbouring_points[0]
plt.scatter(coord[0][idx], coord[1][idx])
```

3. your radius is probably too small. So inside of `np.where` check for something like `<= 400` instead. Otherwise you only get back your central point at `coord[0][10], coord[1][10]`
4. If your central point is too close to the board of your 1000x1000 square, you also wont get a full circle. You can fix that by choosing your central to be i.e. `500,500` in your circle equation

So in total:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord=[]
    
    
x=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
y=np.random.randint(1000, size=1000)
    
coord.append(x)     
coord.append(y)

neighbouring_points = np.where(np.sqrt((coord[0]-500)**2 + (coord[1]-500)**2)<=400,) 
idx = neighbouring_points[0]
plt.scatter(coord[0][idx],coord[1][idx], color='blue')
```

[image]